# FreeLibrary blocks my application

Tags: c++, dll

Good day, everyone!

I wrote some dll, which I use in my project. In constuctor of class I load library `lib = LoadLibrary(L"library.dll");`, in destructor I free it using 
`if (lib)
    FreeLibrary(lib);`

Some times applications blocks when FreeLibrary is called, what I am doing wrong?

I implement dllMain but this is not solve my problem =(

in .h file

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain( HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved );

extern "C" {
    static projector::CProjCorrectionsClient* corrections;

    void DLLPROJECTOR_EXPORT CorrectionsInit    (const char* configFile);
    void DLLPROJECTOR_EXPORT CorrectionsApply   ();
}
```

in cpp file

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain( HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved )
{
    switch( fdwReason )
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            qDebug() << "DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH";
            corrections = new projector::CProjCorrectionsClient();
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            qDebug() << "DLL_PROCESS_DEATTACH";
            delete corrections;
            qDebug() << "Corrections delete success";
            break;
    }
    qDebug() << "Out side dllmain switch";
    return TRUE; 
}
```

On console I see this messages:

DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH 
Out side dllmain switch 
<...>
Try to release library 
DLL_PROCESS_DEATTACH 
Corrections delete success 
Out side dllmain switch

There is no message after FreeLibrary call and applications freeze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question should maybe be - 'what is the dll doing wrong?'.  If the library is going to be unloaded because its ref count has reached zero then FreeLibrary will give the dll a chance to clean up, and will call DllMain with DLL_PROCESS_DETACH.  Perhaps try debugging the dll to see whats going on when this event occurs.
Also if there is any static data in the DLL that could run destructors then perhaps the issue lies there.

Comment: There is no dllMain in my dll and destructors are called some where else, but it looks wrong. I will try to create dllMain and se what is going on.

Comment: I implement dllMain but this is not solve my problem =(

See questions for details

Comment: Maybe your dll is also calling FreeLibrary, in a destructor somewhere?  this could cause deadlock, since FreeLibrary has a critical section in it

Comment: Maybe the solution is to have initialize and cleanup functions exported from your dll that the client must call.

Comment: There is no calls of FreeLibrary in my lib, I have release function, that must be called before freelib, all data delete from there

Comment: What are the call stacks for _all threads_ when running under the debugger and your application is locked up?  Perhaps amend your post with this information, otherwise you're just stabbing in the dark.

Comment: Also, if any of the threads are in windows api functions etc, make sure you set up debugging symbols appropriately to the Microsoft symbol server.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are not waiting for some thread inside DLL_PROCESS_DETACH.

When DllMain is called, system aquires internal critical section, which can cause deadlock if your code inside DllMain waits for some thread T to finish, this thread when finishing will also want to do DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, but since system critical section is aquired it will wait infinitelly causing deadlock.

Comment: How it can be fixed, and how to find out whitch thread is blocking? I'm not create any threads manualy